# Why isn't my binary to English code working?

Tags: java, binary, converters

I am trying to make a translator that will convert english into my custom binary, and vice versa. It works translating english to binary, but not binary to english. Could someone help me please and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I would like to input something like "01000 00101 01100 01100 01111" and get "HELLO" as an out put. Right now the program only allows me to input one character at a time. For example, I input "01000" and I get h. But when I input something like "01000 00101" I get the same thing back. I would like to know how to fix this.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Translator
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )

    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.print( "Would you like to convert English to Binary (yes or no)? " );
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        if( answer.equals( "yes" ) )
        {
        System.out.println( "Enter English text here: " );
        String english = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println( stringToBinary( english ) );
        }
        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase( "no" ) )
        {
            System.out.print( "Binary to English? " );
            String answer2 = input.nextLine();
            if (answer2.equalsIgnoreCase( "yes" ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "Enter Binary text here: " );
                // enter binary here
                String code = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println( stringToEnglish( code ) );
            }
        }
    }

    public static String encode (String toEncode)
    {
        String binary = toEncode;

        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            binary = "00001";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
            binary = "00010";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            binary = "00011";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
            binary = "00100";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
            binary = "00101";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
            binary = "00110";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
            binary = "00111";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))
            binary = "01000";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))
            binary = "01001";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("j"))
            binary = "01010";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("k"))
            binary = "01011";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
            binary = "01100";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
            binary = "01101";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            binary = "01110";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("o"))
            binary = "01111";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
            binary = "10000";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
            binary = "10001";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("r"))
            binary = "10010";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
            binary = "10011";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
            binary = "10100";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("u"))
            binary = "10101";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("v"))
            binary = "10110";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("w"))
            binary = "10111";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
            binary = "11000";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            binary = "11001";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase("z"))
            binary = "11010";
        if (toEncode.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            binary = " ";

        return binary;
    }


    public static String stringToBinary( String text )
    {

        String newText = "";
        String selectedChar;
        String convertedChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {


            selectedChar = text.charAt(i) + "";


            convertedChar = encode(selectedChar);

            if (convertedChar.equals(" ")) 
            {
                newText = newText + " ";
            }

            else
            {
                newText = newText + convertedChar;
                if (!convertedChar.equals(" "))
                {
                    newText = newText + " ";
                }
            }
        }

        return newText;
    }

    public static String stringToEnglish( String text )
    {

        String english = text;

        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00001"))
            english = "a";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00010"))
            english = "b";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00011"))
            english = "c";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00100"))
            english = "d";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00101"))
            english = "e";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00110"))
            english = "f";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00111"))
            english = "g";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01000"))
            english = "h";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01001"))
            english = "i";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01010"))
            english = "j";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01011"))
            english = "k";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01100"))
            english = "l";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01101"))
            english = "m";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01110"))
            english = "n";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("01111"))
            english = "o";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10000"))
            english = "p";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10001"))
            english = "q";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10010"))
            english = "r";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10011"))
            english = "s";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10100"))
            english = "t";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10101"))
            english = "u";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10110"))
            english = "v";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("10111"))
            english = "w";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("11000"))
            english = "x";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("11001"))
            english = "y";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("11010"))
            english = "z";
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
            english = " ";

        return english ;
    }

}
```

Comment: It sure would help if the down voters would state why. As for your question, we need to know what you are expecting as output before we can say why it isn't working

Comment: Use a debugger to run your code step by step and you will find out what's wrong.

Comment: Not really a complete answer so this is a comment, but this _should_ help - `StringBuilder` and a loop.

Comment: @jdphenix Where would you suggest I insert that? I am just starting out.

Comment: The structure of your `stringToEnglish()` method should be similar to your `stringToBinary()` method - within `stringToBinary()` you convert each character to your representation - now do the inverse in `stringToEnglish()`

Comment: As a side project, you could greatly simplify the conversion algorithms to return a value from an equation realizing characters can be represented as numbers as well.

Comment: @jdphenix so both my stringToBinary() and stringToEnglish() should have if if statements? like if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("00001"))
   english = "a";

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils So I would just end up looping that equation? I'm not very experienced with such things, yet.

Comment: No, instead of the long `if` chain you'd have an equation that's able to provide the correct results with, potentially, a single line of code. Like I said, a side project.

Comment: @EdenMyagi Not quite - the `stringToEnglish()` method should loop through each group of digits, and convert each in order.

Comment: @jdphenix I apologize for the basic questions I have, but from the tutorials I've watched there are many different types of loops and I'm not sure how to execute that.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'll definitely consider that! I'll work on the distilling this into an equation after I sort out the problem I have at hand!

Comment: Your long if chain introduces another problem of cyclomatic complexity.  Id personally load your hex into a map or another object of similar function.  As far as your input issue have you stepped through your code?

Comment: @EdenMyagi If you're still online later today I might be able to chat with you.

Comment: @bcar I'd like the program to ask the user if they want to convert to english or binary. and when the user has chosen what they wanna do, the program will either go to the respectable code that has the respective part of the code where the switching will take place. I don't know where I really went wrong in the part of the code where the program is supposed to convert binary into english letters. I recently just started learning Java, and this is the best I could do from watching tutorials online.

Comment: @jdphenix that'd be great! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `stringToEnglish` method only computes a single character so it will never return a valid result for more than that. What you need is a loop, a `StringBuilder` and a bit of a change in your comparison.

First thing, using a `StringBuilder` is the best choice for building a string. Strings are immutable so in fact each time you add to one a new instance is returned. `StringBuilder` is a way around this.

```
public static String stringToEnglish( String text )
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    ...
```

We also need to notice you have two instances to take care of:

1. When your string starts with a " "

   When your string a binary "00001"

so the loop you need to process more than a single character would look like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 4; ++i) { 
...
```

An optimization would be to jump to the end of the string when it's binary.
We also need to consider we are iterating the original string by looking at sub-strings...

```
if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
    continue;
} else if (text.substring(i, i + 5).equalsIgnoreCase("00001")){
    builder.append( "a" );   
}
...
```

First, we'll see if it begins with a `" "`, if so continue. Using `else if` instead of a chain of ifs to avoid needless comparisons. If not, we know it's a binary representation and need to pull it as a sub-string and test it against your "table"; when you find it - append it.

We continue until we've reached the end, as much as we can go, then we will return what we've built...

```
    return builder.toString() ;
}
```

You could also use a `switch` with `break` ,or better use my suggestion in the commentary, as opposed to the long if chain.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! My program works as I had planned! I appreciate your effort.